# change line of text in PHP file when parsed

Tags: php

I am using Vanilla 2 forum and i want to translate the line "New comment" just above the textarea. But the forum script includes almost 1000 .php files. Maybe it is also possible that it is already put in the DB. How can i search efficiently for that line of text?
[image: snapshot webpage]
Website: http://www.webprofis.nl

Comment: I can't read anything in the image you posted. Maybe next time only include the cropped screenshot? We only need to see the upper dialog, right?

Comment: i suggest grep -ri "new comment" *

Comment: the image: http://www.jackmaessen.nl/test/images/snapcomment.png

Answer (score 0):

You have to use vanilla internationalization.
Read this  http://vanillaforums.org/docs/localization